# Что нужно знать для создания сайтов

Tags: mysql, html, ruby, javascript, ruby-on-rails

Посоветуйте, а то глаза расходятся.

Я новичок и есть желание научиться что-то толковое создавать в этой сфере. Вот что необходимо знать?
Весь перечень, который я знаю, можете дополнять):

---

1. База:
   HTML + CSS
2. JavaScript библиотеки,технологии:
   Atom. Js, jQuery.js, node.js, ajax,
3. База данных:
   MySQL.
4. Серверный язык:
   Ruby, php, c #, java, python,jsp ,perl,go,asp.net
5. IDE:
   Phpdesigner,PHPStorm,WebStorm,SublimeText2, NetBeans
6. html редакторы:
   Dreamweaver,
7. фреймворки:
   ruby / rails, python / django,Kohana,Zend Framework,Cake PHP,YII

---

Так что я выбрал для изучения:

1. База:
   HTML + CSS
2. JavaScript библиотеки,технологии:
   jQuery.js, ajax,
3. База данных:
   MySQL.
4. Серверный язык:
   Ruby
5. IDE:
   Вакансия
6. Фреймворки:
   Ruby on Rails

---

Я Выбрал ruby вместо php, это правильно? Не понимаю для чего фреймворки. И стоит ли html редакторы использовать, или в "блокноте"? Прошу посоветовать. Готов слушать какой я плохой)

Я думаю, что  база данных - это потом. Не думайте, что я выбрал `ruby`, потому что на php много быдлокодеров и  школоты и тому подобное. Я и на `ruby` смогу написать говнокод, пока каша не пройдет). А `html` редактор нужен? Мне кажется что лучше будет без него.   
canvas. Какую библиотеку лучше использовать? Атом?

Comment: ajax это технология, а не библиотека. И зачем phpDesigner если ruby?

Comment: 1.Задача с сайтом била поставлена,до изучения аз html)))
2.Я вкурсе,просто не хочу придумувать велосипеди.
3.Так и делаю ,и буду делать.

Comment: http://sharpc.livejournal.com/67583.html

пункт 32, я не со всем согласен, но лучше трудно сказать.

Comment: > Редакторы:

Редактор и IDE это разные вещи!

Comment: мда...ну и вопросы пошли, да ладно еще, что такой вопрос был задан, но вот то что его не закрыли и он собрал плюсов уже огорчает((

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Всё смешали в кашу. По порядку, что вам нужно для создания динамического сайта:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. Javascript
4. PHP
5. MYSQL

Для начала вам этого хватит. Пока не будет базового понимания javascript - библиотеки вам особо не помогут, как и фреймворки. Редактор я использую PHPStorm и WebStorm. C Ruby советую подождать (хотя бы потому что не на каждом хостинге он есть и проще поднять свой VDS, но там еще дополнительный стек знаний нужен), но если вам понравился этот язык - то замените четвертый пункт на Ruby + RoR.

Comment: >учиться надо не PHP, а программировать

золотые слова

Comment: Я пробовул как рыба наживку, мне понравилось.Пока пробовал съел базу.База есть в умении использования html + css + простой javascript, для простых изменений на сторинци.ООП-я не розберал, и чтото НЕ хочется, люблю когда ево нет.Почав смотреть на php, но ево много людей не любят, и счас думаю взять ruby начать учить.Я также пробувал С++.С придумуванием алгоритмов беды нет.Бо меня сначала движет идея ,а потом я ее воплощаю.

Comment: @Олег24, а вы думайте своей головой. Его многие не любят? А работать с ним будете вы или они? Вот и выбирайте то, что больше нравится вам. Сайт создает не язык, а программист. Язык играет роль лишь для самых начинающих.

Comment: Всегда можно попробувать,сечас приоритет -ruby.

Comment: сорри @Олег24 у тебя как с русския языком? мне аж читать неприятно все комментарии твои. 24 в нике - это возраст? если да то жесть.


+пробовул
+попробувать
+придумувании
+розберал
+ево
+почав
+счас

я язык сломал читать комментарии.

Comment: Прости,я исправлюсь.
24-день рождения.
Мне 20 лет.
Учусь в университете(UA,Львов) на гидравлике, понял что это не мое. И теперь хочу веб изучать.   
"я язык сломал читать комментарии."-не читай вслух)

Comment: >"я язык сломал читать комментарии."-не читай вслух)

ну тогда можно мозг сломать об эту безграмотность.

Answer (score 12):

Вам здесь очень много и упорно советовали php. Так вот для полноты картины я посоветую что-нибудь, но НЕ PHP. Пусть это будет C# с ASP.NET, Python, Ruby, но не php. Признаюсь, я не люблю этот язык, и, возможно, несколько предвзято к нему отношусь. Но все же постараюсь привести адекватные доводы в пользу этой точки зрения.

Бесспорно, php хорош для создания сайтов-визиток и всяких прочих интернет-магазинов, кроме того, в случае с этим языком нет проблем с хостингами. Но проблема в том что:

1. php слишком прост (да, это плохо). Отсюда следует то, что на нем пишет любой имбецил, у которого есть пальцы, чтобы стучать ими по клавиатуре. А это значит, что придется конкурировать с толпами школоты, согласной писать тонны говнокода за бигмак. Вряд ли это можно назвать пределом мечтаний в карьере.
2. Php склонен прощать программисту все, что он наговнокодит. Сядьте на клавиатуру и попрыгайте на ней, пардон, задницей, и весьма вероятно, что то, что получилось, сможет быть интерперетировано, как корректный скрипт на php. Думаете, это хорошо? Как бы не так - вседозволенность губит даже программистов.
3. Задачи, обычно стоящие перед php-программистом, редко требуют сколько-нибудь высокой квалификации. Отсюда - отсутствие профессионального роста и святая вера программиста в то, он уже крутой чувак, и дорос до небес. Излишне говорить, что это конец
4. Неудачная спроектированность самого языка. Один только факт, что глобальное пространство имен захламлено миллионом функций уже говорит о многом. Сюда еще надо добавить проблемы с поддержкой UTF-8 (в XXI-то веке!), отсутствие поддержки многопоточности, отсутствие обратной совместимости между версиями языка, кучу функций, выполняющих сходные действия, но реализованных разными группами программистов, и потому имеющих разные префиксы и порядок следования аргументов...ну и много-много чего еще
5. Всячечкие неочевидные проблемы, вызываемые динамической типизацией
6. Низкая зарплата опять же

Ну и напоследок цитата:

> В одном интервью с кем-то из руководителей Гугла спросили «Используете ли Вы и если да то как php в Гугл?». На что получили ответ «Да, используем… У нас в офисе есть страничка, через которую мы пиццу заказываем… Так вот, ОНА написана на php.»

Так вот, все вышесказанное не преследует цели очернить славный php  - есть немало php-программистов очень высокой квалификации, зарабатывающих очень хорошие деньги. Это лишь желание сказать, что php не так хорош, как может показаться на первый взгляд

Comment: >> конкурировать с толпами школоты,

*Но почему школоты?!* Намного больше подходит "быдлокодеры"

А среди школоты не все дураки. И конкуренция со школьниками есть везде.  Я, java программер, в свои 12 лет. И это не значит, что я плохокодер. И таких как я кучка наберется, я думаю. 

Так что *школота != быдлокодеры"

Comment: В моем понимании школота != школьник. Школота - это собирательное название для малограмотных самоуверенных и бездарных подростков, не более того. Так вот, когда такие люди пытаются заниматься программированием, то ничего кроме быдлокодеров из них вырасти не может по определению. А то, что школьник не может быть хорошим/неплохим программистом, я не говорил.

Comment: @DreamChild Вообщем всё упирается в терминологию :). 

И всё-таки из малограмотных и самоуверенных (но не через чур) подростков может что-то получиться. Ну а у бездарных конечно нет

Comment: @danpetruk, согласен, но каждый год ты будешь оборачиваться и говорить: "какой же я дурак был год назад! как дебильно я написал то-то и то-то". И это хорошо. И да, кстати, школота != показатель_возраста, школота == состояние_души, школота != школьник.

Comment: @Zelta я каждые полгода так оборачиваюсь :)

Comment: Я за  Ruby.Много начитался про нелюбовь к php,склалось враження что он как Delphi. Но если не понравится,то буду учить чтото другое.

Comment: не знаю, чтоименно вы имеете в виду, говоря, что "он как Delphi@/ но кое-что общее у них точно есть - php сейчас занимает ту нишу, которую занимал delphi (а точнее,  pascal) лет 15 назад - с него многие начинают

Comment: Я просто учил в школе pascal , и хотел изучать Delphi.Но потом увидел С++.А потом попробувал веб-розроботку.И сечас на нем остановился.Просто когда делаєш здесь чтото ,то сразу видно результат.Мне ето нравтся.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что пхпшникам мало платят. Посмотрите зарплаты на сайтах по поиску работы, да на фриланс сайтах. С остальным, в принципе, согласен.

Comment: хорошо платят квалифицированным phpшникам Таких относительно общего количества очень мало

Comment: Уважаемый г-н минусатор, прошу аргументированно объяснить, с чем именно вы не согласны, а не молча минусовать

Comment: В PHP скорее проблемы не с языком, для реализации всячески сложных задач там есть все возможности, и нормально там и с кодировками и с зарплатами. Дело тут действительно в том, что большинство даже зеленого понятия о программировании не имеют зато сайты они уже делают. У php много минусов но есть и бесспорные плюсы для web. Но я согласен с @DreamChild надо учить не PHP, т.к. сразу же попадете в то число людей которые больше никогда ничего хорошего не выучат. Надо учить хорошо структурированный язык со всеми его качествами.  Я бы посоветовал С#.

Comment: > отсутствие поддержки многопоточности

ИМХО это не есть однозначный минус

Answer (score 4):

PHP - штука хорошая, но может портить людей. Самое, на мой взгляд, главное - понять основы, учиться надо не PHP, а программировать. Если с этим все хорошо - то вперед, хоть PHP, хоть Ruby. От себя порекомендую django за четкую структурированность, хотя да, работа фреймворков без понимания основ кажется магией.

**UPD:**
Вот еще чего вспомнил: чтобы создавать нормальные сайты нужно или работать в команде с дизайнером и/или фронтэндщиком или знать ну хоть основы дизайна, ибо помните, конечный пользователь увидит не красоту Вашего кода, а Ваш сайт.
Ну и про SEO тоже почитайте, основы знать полезно всегда.

Answer (score 3):

Хорошо Роман ответил, я тоже считаю, что начать надо с PHP. Проблем с хостингами не будет, только, если с версией, но это легко решается средствами общения с техподдержкой. Или внимательным изучением спецификаций перед покупкой.

Фреймворки вещь нужная и полезная. Они помогают избавиться от нудной работы, повысить безопастность, производительность и потом просто поддерживать свои и чужие проекты, но Здесь много раз поднимались вопросы какой из них лучше, что выбрать и т. п. [смотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/176769/framework-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-php) 
Я считаю, что лучший тот, на котором приятно писать и получаешь удовольствие от проделанной работы. Я использую [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)  и очень доволен.

Код пишу в  [SublimeText2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) волшебная вещь, перешел на него с  [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) но есть и + и -

Тут только Вы сами решите, что удобнее. Но начинать лучше с более простого.

Comment: Kohana и Sublime замечательные вещи, но начинать с них, пожалуй, не стоит. С фреймворка уж точно. Чтобы понять как действительно всё работает, а не воспринимать работу фреймворка как магию, надо познакомиться с ООП. Мне кажется, что до этого лучше доехать своими велосипедами и шишками. И книжки читать :)

Comment: книжки надо в любом случае читать.
Согласен, что с фреймврков не начинают, но вопрос был такой "Не понимаю для чего фреймворки."

Comment: Вивод:фреймворк потом.

Comment: по поводу хостингов - будет спрос, будет и предложение.

Comment: > надо познакомиться с ООП

а так-же с MVC, AJAX и другими модными словами

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить дельный совет лучше поставить конкретную цель. К примеру: "хочу написать то-то и то-то, чем лучше воспользоваться?", а если просто хобби такое тогда яб начал именно с HTML CSS и JavaScript. Писать лучше на WeBuilder. В блокноте лучше писать заметки ;)

Но всё это индивидуально и зависит от уровня поставленной цели опять-же. На сегодняшний день не обязательно учиться программировать, чтобы потом делать сайты, а программирование - математика, без которой программированию не бывать вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, вам тут уже много чего насоветовали.

Я бы вместо Ruby советовал бы вам обратить внимание на python. ИМХО он проще ruby, изящнее, но при этом довольно строгий, говнокодить на нем можно, но сложно(сравните код, написанный на руби с кодом, на питоне). И этот говнокод будет какой-никакой читаемостью, но обладать)

Для начала изучите HTML+CSS2. Сделайте статичный сайт-визитку. Потом, к примеру, можете начать добавлять на него красивости в виде анимаций всплывающих меню, картинок. Можете сделать галерею. Тут уже вам придется познакомиться с CSS3, и js. на css3 можно делать клевые эффекты, бесспорно, но иногда на javascript проще и быстрее. Тут, как раз, познакомитесь с самым популярным фреймворком - jquery.

После того, как освоите эти технологии, можете начиинать добавлять всякие динамически изменяемые страницы в свой сайт. Кстати, javascript можно выполнять и на сервере - смотрите в сторону [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/). Ну, т.е., если вам javascript понравится, вам даже не придется изучать никаких новых серверных языков, потому что вы знаете javascript.

Про хостинг. На самом деле, довольно много хостингов под различные популярные языки программирования. Да, для php их больше, но и для руби, и для питона, и для ноды сможете найти хостинг без особых проблем.

Про БД. В принципе, mysql вам на первое время хватит.

Comment: Уже качаю книгы по ryby)

Comment: jquery работает на клиенте, RoR - на сервере.

Comment: Так и думал)

Comment: jQuery - это библиотека. jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2):

Метаясь очень продолжительное время между технологиями для back-end, я буквально вчера выбрал Ruby. Руководствовался следующими критериями:

1. Ruby - красивый язык и можно получать реальное удовольствие, программируя на нем. Nuff said. Его преимущества подробно расписывать не буду, о них можно почитать в Википедии
2. Обратная совместимость между версиями (по сравнению со вторым и третьим питоном)
3. Фреймворк Ruby on Rails у всех на слуху, и у заказчиков тоже
4. Сравнительно небольшая конкуренция, а как следствие высокие зарплаты, если работать на дядю
5. Множество необходимых плюшек доступны "из коробки" (как в рельсах, так и в самом руби). Имею опыт программирования на Django и в нем мне не понравилось то, что очень многое нужно прикручивать дополнительно, фактически собирая проект из запчастей
6. Огромное количество обучающих материалов в свободном доступе
7. Дружное, отзывчивое комьюнити

В остальном время покажет)

Answer (score 0):

PHP это болезнь! А Ruby - сойдёт. Если всё-же рубик не понравится, то вот варианты:

- python
- jsp
- perl
- go
- asp.net (правда это каша всего и вся)
- и др.

Погуглите по этому списку, много полезного узнаете.

Минусы php:

1. Слишком простой, поэтому превращает человека в быдлокодера, не думающего, а пишущего быдлокод, который работает медленно и глючно
2. Самый небезопасный язык
3. Слишком гибкий, что приводит к ошибкам в стиле "не пойми где, не пойми почему"
4. Самые низкооплачиваемый язык программирования.
5. и др.

Comment: Да, полностью с вами согласен. Слишком простой и слишком гибкий язык. Это ужасно.

Comment: А еще он заставляет человека думать, что он знает все лучше других... Не знаю, почему, но закономерность налицо)

Comment: @Zelta, это характеристика человека, а не языка программирования. В т.ч. и превращаемость в быдлокодера. Написать медленный и глючный код можно на любом языке.

Comment: >asp.net (правда это каша всего и вся)

в чем конкретно "каша"?

Comment: >> в чем конкретно "каша"?
:

>> ASP.NET опирается на многоязыковые возможности .NET, что позволяет писать код страниц на VB.NET, Delphi.NET, Visual C#, J# и т. д.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asp.net

Comment: ну и что же? Это недостаток по-вашему?

Comment: >Написать медленный и глючный код можно на любом языке

но если этому способствует еще и сам язык, то это в таком случае становится характеристикой не только человека, но и языка

Comment: @DreamChild конечно нет! Просто я хотел сказать, что asp.net состоит из нескольких технологий

Comment: Я тут чуть-чуть позанудствую: во-первых, не нужно путать ASP и ASP.NET (первый практичиски уже не используется)  во-вторых, то, что вы перечислили - это языки, а не технологии. И в-третьих, писать ASP.NET  приложения из всех этих языков можно, пожалуй, только на C# и Visual Basic. На всем прочем - крайне маловероятно

Comment: Вроде туда как-то можно и c++ прикрутить (либо это ошибка в памяти моего мозга)

Comment: Так и зделаю."asp.net (правда это каша всего и вся)"- я верю что ето каша,много того,что майкрософт - каша,я пробивал в винде создать окно с директом.

Comment: > PHP это болезнь! 
Болезнь, это когда автор неадекват. А PHP - это язык программирования.