# Создание логинов и паролей на страницы

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.

Я создаю свой сайт. Мне нужно, чтобы любому, кто зайдёт на него, был доступ только к некоторым страницам, а остальные были запаролены. Т.е., например, как работает сайт Вконтакте, где у любого человека есть доступ только к заглавной странице (для зарегистрированных пользователей ещё и к своей странице). Также мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы у каждой страницы были свой логин и пароль, и желательно, чтобы их нельзя было взломать (т.е. лучше было бы, если создать отдельный файл со всеми логинами и паролями).

Если это возможно, то напишите, пожалуйста, как это сделать, а то мне приходится лазить по всему интернету, рыскать HTML коды и собирать сайт по маленьким частям.  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую Вам начинать изучать основы в следующей последовательности:

1. HTML.
2. CSS.
3. JavaScript.
4. PHP.
5. MySQL.
6. jQuery.
7. ООП, особенно MVC.

Зная все эти вещи, можно написать отличный сайт!

Пароли никогда хранить в файле нельзя, тем более в открытом виде!
Для этих вещей тебе необходимо создать БД (MySQL) и таблицу user, в которой будешь хранить всю информацию о конкретном пользователе, а также пароль, но только не в открытом виде. Можно зашифровать элементарным и безопасным md5.

***P.S.*** Если вы пишите сайт, чтобы научиться программировать, то изучите все пункты, которые я описал выше. А если Вам сайт нужен для показа какой-либо информации, продажи товаров или что-либо, то тут посоветую использовать готовую CMS.

Comment: Из этих пунктов мне знакомы только 1,2,3,4. Остальное пока что тёмный лес)

Comment: Берите готовую бесплатную CMS. Лично я использую Joomla.

Comment: Ну так не теряйте время, начинайте изучать. 
Я бы посоветовал для начала изучить frameWork CodeIgniter
Ссылка на фреймворк: http://code-igniter.ru/

Его необходимо скачать, установить и пользоваться!  Он написан на чистом MVC. 
Я еще в институте на нем написал сайте по продаже автомобилей, дипломная работа! Ушло на изучение всех выше описанных пунктов и создания сайта - около 3-4 месяцев.

Никита__, если Вам дали правильный или исчерпывающий ответ, то не забывайте его отмечать как правильный.

Comment: @МаринаВоин 3-4 месяца на вышеперечисленные пункты? Что вы тогда понимаете под словом изучение? Может быть ознакомление?

Comment: 3-4 месяца, это изучение основ по каждому пункту и написание функционального сайта. 
После чего мой уровень был: junior(новичек).
Сейчас прошло 1,5 года и я уже уверенный middle разработчик. Который многие из пунктов знает в совершенстве.

Comment: @МаринаВоин "в совершенстве", все понятно, откланиваюсь.

Comment: ООП, особенно MVC - а с какого MVC относится к ООП? зачем человека водить в заблуждение

Comment: @smackmychi видать, вам в жизни одни валенки попадались ;)

Comment: @ale_x тогда уж «Он написан на чистом MVC» — а с какого MVC относится к ЯП?

Comment: @Ale_x вы не в курсе, что в объектно-ориентированном программировании используется активная модель MVC? Знать ООП и не знать MVC - это значит ничего не знать.

@Ale_x, Из вашего комментария я могу сделать вывод, что вы не знакомы  с Codeigniter. И не понимаете паттерна MVC.

Comment: MVC - это паттерн проектирования. В его определении ничего не сказано про ООП.  Можно и в процедурном языке спокойно заюзать MVC. "Знать ООП и не знать MVC" - это значит ничего не знать - ГРОМКОЕ УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ midlle разработчика со стажем 1.5 года, знающий все выше им указанное в совершенстве.  Дайте ссылку на определение ООП, в котором говорится о том, что MVC является частью его парадигмы?

Comment: @Ale_x предлагаю окончить данный вброс и дать человеку дальше спокойно набивать себе карму на ресурсе.

Comment: Зачем вы все скандалите на пустом месте? Изначально, до редактирования, спросили - как на HTML\JS ограничить доступ к странице :) Все подсказали, кто CMS, кто Framework. Что еще дальше?

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, а дальше вон учить до совершенства за 3-4 месяца...

Comment: Да нет, не на пустом месте. Если человек заявляет о себе как о midlle разработчике, говорит, что знает в совершенстве - то ему не простительно путать терминологии и смешивать их неразрывными связями. Помимо MVC, есть еще MVVM, HMVC. И не стоит утверждать, что MVC это некоторый 'грааль' и что без него уже чихнуть при разработке нельзя.

P.S. Программист - это не тот кто знает в совершенстве язык(функции, паттерны и прочие),а тот который умеет думать логически, понимает что он делает, умеет анализировать чужой код и самое главное знает куда копать - если на поставленную задачу не хватает знаний

Answer (score 1):

По авторизации смотрите php сессии, также нужны азы работы с бд (MySQl, например), но это все не так просто, как кажется. В Вашем случае, я думаю, идеальный вариант был бы Wordpress либо Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны очень хорошо, что Вы сами пишете (разбираетесь) в коде сайта. Но зачем изобретать велосипед? Не проще взять подходящую для сайта CMS и далее разбираться. Ну и напоследок, одними HTML и JS Вы полнофункциональный сайт измучаетесь строить.

Answer (score 0):

А вы сайт пишите на html небось. А сервер на чем у вас?

С таким вопросом вам, похоже, прийдется тут написать большую лекцию про то, как вообще все устроено. Может, кто-то этим и займется, но лично я бы предпочел перенаправить вас искать материалы типа «с чего начать», коих на этом форуме много. Мне вспоминается [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210522/javascript-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), хотя есть и другие.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос (все-таки прийдется написать абзац-другой). html и css отвечают исключительно за внешний вид страницы. js — за поведение. Но этого не достаточно, чтобы все заработало. Всм нужна структура, которая все это контролирует. Живет она на сервере и написана на серверных языках (я сторонник python, многие используют php, вообще тут наблюдается холивар, но у каждого языка есть свои особенности, обуславливающие его применимость в данной конкретной ситуации).

Так вот, именно сервер решает, что показывать посетителю. Он принимает запрос, выполняет какую-то логику (возможно, обращается в базу данных) и отсылает сгенерированный html клиенту. И будет в этом html сообщение «добро пожаловать» или «введите пароль» или еще что — решает сервер. Соответственно, читайте про языки и архитектуру серверной части.

Про аутентификацию пользователей и сессии тоже много чего можно сказать, но я не уверен, что если сейчас углубиться в эту тему, оно пойдет вам на пользу. Скорее создаст непонимание.